# CURL command with --data-raw JSON, Unexpected character error

Tags: json, curl

Hi I need to send JSON format through the CURL command but I am getting an error.

```
curl --request POST "https://app.io/api/graphql?accountId=Xzg" --header "x-api-key: WHpnV=" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-raw "{applications(limit: 2) {nodes {name}}}"
```

So the problematic part is **data-raw**, although I have checked it online it's Valid JSON.

```
--data-raw "{applications(limit: 2) {nodes {name}}}"
```

Response:

```
{"metaData":null,"resource":null,"responseMessages":[{"code":"DEFAULT_ERROR_CODE","level":"ERROR",
"message":"Unable to process JSON Unexpected character ('a' (code 97)): 
    was expecting double-quote to start field name","exception":null,"failureTypes":[]}]}
```

I tried different ways how I could change this request data but without success.
Can someone please assist me how I should change this query which was definitely generated as the proper one from some app.
Thanks!

Comment: Is `{applications(limit: 2) {nodes {name}}}` supposed to be JSON? Because it most definitely isn't valid JSON! It's not even close to being valid.

Comment: `"{applications(limit: 2) {nodes {name}}}"` would be valid JSON though as is simply a string value, however, that is not how it's being interpreted by the API.

Comment: @phuzi https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer this site also confirms it is valid JSON. if you copy-paste the `"{applications(limit: 2) {nodes {name}}}"` and click on JSON Validator option. Can you please assist further how I should pass it with quotes or whatever additionally is needed? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
 --data-raw '{"query": "{applications(limit: 2) {nodes {name}}}" }'
```

Comment: There we go, the full JSON. Without visibility of the API there was no way we could have guessed the answer.